# Implement login facebook for android

Tags: android

I am creating an app for android that uses the facebook login. My question is: is to create a screen with fields username and password to lgin on facebook? because I do not want to use one's own facebook small screen that is called when you click the button to login.

Explaining ...
I want on my main screen I have a button "Login with Facebook" and when the user clicks on this button will open two fields (username and password) and login button to confirm.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and use Facebook's login screen:

1. It's common and well known to the user
2. The users won't have to share their personal login info with you, which is probably against Facebook's terms.
3. Much easier to implement